# How to use the hardware acceleration for ffmepg on m1-max?

Tags: ffmpeg, apple-m1, apple-silicon

Since there aren't m1 builds available from ffmpeg.org, I had to compile my own. Obviously, I'd like to get the best possible performance.

- Does ffmpeg use the "Hardware-accelerated H.264" on the m1 max?
- Is there anything I need to do, like compiler flags, to get it?
- Any switch at run time?
- How can I verify that it's being used?

To compile ffmpeg, I just did the basics:

```
./configure --prefix=/tmp/ff       --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree   --enable-libx264
make
make install
```

For x264, I just did
./configure --prefix=/tmp/ff
make
make install

to run:

```
ffmpeg -i random.wmv -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast  -c:a aac  output-ultra.mp4
```

Anything else I should be doing?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like what I wanted was [videotoolbox](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/videotoolbox)

Usage is documented [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro), basically

```
To use H.264/HEVC hardware encoding in macOS, just use the encoder -c:v h264_videotoolbox
```

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i random.wmv -c:v h264_videotoolbox    -c:a aac  junk-vt.mp4
```

Seems to be slightly faster than "ultrafast" with software, and much smaller files.

Comment: `h264_videotoolbox` does not exist on Apple silicon.

Comment: this is working for me, maybe this had been the case, but I'm using `h264_videotoolbox` very successfully on a M1.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

`H264_videotoolbox` is useless on M1 Pro. I don't see that the GPU is working. I use the same file to transcode `h264_videotoolbox` can only play to a 6.x magnification and `-vcodec h264` Use CPU magnification to reach 12.x

Ffmpeg 5.1.2 macos 13.1

[image]

Comment: I'm under the same impression! Has anyone else gotten GPU utilization on Apple Silicon to work with ffmpeg ?